# Combining std::string and std::vector<char>

Tags: c++, string, stl, vector

This is not the actual code, but this represents my problem.

```
std::string str1 = "head";
char *buffer = "body\0body"; // Original code has nullbytes;
std::string str2 = "foot";
std::vector<char> mainStr(buffer, buffer + strlen(buffer));
```

I want to put `str1` and `str2` to `mainStr` in an order:

> headbody\0bodyfoot

So the binary data is maintained. Is this possible to do this?

**PS**: Thanks for telling the `strlen` part is wrong. I just used it to represent `buffer`'s length. :)

Comment: Where do you want to put it? A string, a vector, a stream?

Comment: @Antonio Perez I want to put it in the `mainStr` variable as I've said :). It's `std::vector<char>`

Comment: As a side note: Why do you want to use a `std::vector`? A `std::string` can also store null characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `strlen` as it uses '\0' to determine the end of string.  However, the following will do what you are looking for:

```
std::string head = "header";
std::string foot = "footer";
const char body[] = "body\0body";

std::vector<char> v;
v.assign(head.begin(), head.end());
std::copy(body, body + sizeof(body)/sizeof(body[0]) - 1, std::back_inserter<std::vector<char> >(v));
std::copy(foot.begin(), foot.end(), std::back_inserter<std::vector<char> >(v));
```

Because the character buffer adds an NUL character at the end of the string, you'll want to ignore it (hence the -1 from the last iterator).

Answer (score 3):

There should be some way of defining length of data in "buffer".
Usually character 0 is used for this and most of standard text functions assume this. So if you use character 0 for other purposes, you have to provide another way to find out length of data.

Just for example:

```
char buffer[]="body\0body";
std::vector<char> mainStr(buffer,buffer+sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]));
```

Here we use array because it provides more information that a pointer - size of stored data.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the difference between `char buffer[]` and `char buffer*`, as `sizeof()` operates on them differently!

Answer (score 2):

btw. `strlen` will not work if there are nul bytes in your string!

The code to insert into the vector is:

front:

```
mainStr.insert(mainStr.begin(), str1.begin(), str1.end());
```

back:

```
mainStr.insert(mainStr.end(), str2.begin(), str2.end());
```

With your code above (using `strlen` will print)

headbodyfoot

EDIT: just changed the `copy` to `insert` as `copy` requires the space to be available I think.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::vector<char>::insert` to append the data you need into `mainStr`.

Something like this:

```
std::string str1 = "head";
char buffer[] = "body\0body"; // Original code has nullbytes;
std::string str2 = "foot";

std::vector<char> mainStr(str1.begin(), str1.end());
mainStr.insert(mainStr.end(), buffer, buffer + sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]));
mainStr.insert(mainStr.end(), str2.begin(), str2.end());
```

**Disclaimer:** I didn't compile it.

Comment: strlen will stop at the first null byte in buffer

Answer (score 1):

You can use IO streams.

```
std::string str1 = "head";
const char *buffer = "body\0body"; // Original code has nullbytes;
std::string str2 = "foot";
std::stringstream ss;
ss.write(str1.c_str(), str1.length())
  .write(buffer, 9) // insert real length here
  .write(str2.c_str(), str2.length());
std::string result = ss.str();

std::vector<char> vec(result.c_str(), result.c_str() + result.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

str1 and str2 are string objects that write the text.

I wish compilers would fail on statements like the declaration of buffer and I don't care how much legacy code it breaks. If you're still building it you can still fix it and put in a const.

You would need to change your declaration of vector because strlen will stop at the first null character. If you did

```
char buffer[] = "body\0body";
```

then sizeof(buffer) would actually give you close to what you want although you'll get the end null-terminator too.

Once your vector mainStr is then set up correctly you could do:

```
std::string strConcat;
strConcat.reserve( str1.size() + str2.size() + mainStr.size() );
strConcat.assign(str1);
strConcat.append(mainStr.begin(), mainStr.end());
strConcat.append(str2);
```

if vector was set up using buffer, buffer+sizeof(buffer)-1

Answer (score 0):

```
 mainStr.resize(str1.length() + str2.length() + strlen(buffer));  
 memcpy(&mainStr[0], &str1[0], str1.length());  
 memcpy(&mainStr[str1.length()], buffer, strlen(buffer));  
 memcpy(&mainStr[str1.length()+strlen(buffer)], &str2[0], str2.length());
```